# how give flutter gcm notification focus on screen

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

i'm finding some issues with the flutter notification , i receive GCM notification well , but they are not showing on the screen.

If for example i have opened another software when i 'm receiving a whatsapp message , the notification appears for short time on the screen. but when i send my notification it make sound but doesn't show , the user will not know he has got new notification if he doesn't scroll down the widget item on the top (that contains bluetooth and others stuffs)

how can i make the notification appears for short times on any screen dat is opened.

here the example of the code i have used:

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    5,
    "Titre notification",
    "body",
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        priority: Priority.high,
        // other properties...
      ),
    ));
```

Sorry for my mistakes i m french.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it on emulator or real device, if real device is it a Huawei or Xiaomi ?

Comment: It is on real device Android Samsung A51,